# ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 90) are incompatible

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, lstm

I want to build a `deep RNN` where my x_train and my y_train. When I execute the code below:

```
print(X_train_fea.shape, y_train_fea.shape)
X_train_res = np.reshape(X_train_fea,(10510,10,1))
y_train_res = np.reshape(y_train_fea.to_numpy(),(-1,1))
print(X_train_res.shape, y_train_res.shape)
```

**result:**

```
(10510, 10) (10510,)
(10510, 10, 1) (10510, 1)
```

and

```
model = Sequential([
    LSTM(90, input_shape=(10,1)), 
])
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

[image: Model summary]

When I fit the model

```
history = model.fit(X_train_res, y_train_res,epochs=5)
```

I got

```
ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 90) are incompatible
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `y_train_res` comprise of integer indices not one-hot vectors. If so you have to use `sparse_categorical_crossentropy`:

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy')
```

and change its shape to 1D:

```
y_train_res = np.reshape(y_train_fea.to_numpy(),(-1,))
```